# SAXParseException and UnmarshalException

Tags: exception, jaxb

I am trying to deal with these exception. For example when a user, loads an invalid XML file, then SAXParseException is thrown and he is asked to load another file.

it seems that "catch" won't work here.

here's my code:

```
public void parseXML_FROM_file (File xml_file)
    {
        try {



           JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance ("generated");

           //Creating an Unmarshaller.
           Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller ();

           //USING FILE APPROACH
           System.out.println("Using FILE approach:");
           JAXBElement element = (JAXBElement) u.unmarshal(xml_file);
           TEST_Class mainTest = (TEST_Class) element.getValue ();



       } catch (JAXBException  e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace ();

       }catch (SAXParseException e)

           //do something

       }catch (UnmarshalException e)

          //do something
       }

   }
```

even, this wont work

```
catch (JAXBException,SAXParseException,UnmarshalException e)
{
  //do something
}
```

@don robi

this is what i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type JAXBException is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <SAXParseException, UnmarshalException>
    Syntax error on token ",", < expected
    Syntax error, insert ">" to complete ReferenceType1

    at XML_Parser.parseXML_FROM_file(XML_Parser.java:64)
    at Main_Class.main(Main_Class.java:13)
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?  What is the behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that this is a compilation exception.  Once the errors are fixed in your XML_parser class you should get the JAXB behaviour you are expecting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The type JAXBException is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <SAXParseException, UnmarshalException>
    Syntax error on token ",", < expected
    Syntax error, insert ">" to complete ReferenceType1

    at XML_Parser.parseXML_FROM_file(XML_Parser.java:64)
    at Main_Class.main(Main_Class.java:13)
```